# DNS address could not be founde dingaros

Tags: reactjs, deployment, netlify

when opening the site with the domain name from Netlify  sends me "this site can't be reached" I have 3 domains

with this error in every device when opening and the internet is fastly and does not have a problem

**[shimmering-phoenix-977e7f.netlify.app](https://shimmering-phoenix-977e7f.netlify.app/) => Netlify subdomain**

**[www.whale4trade.com](https://www.whale4trade.com/) => Primary domain**

**[whale4trade.com](https://whale4trade.com/) **=>Redirects automatically to primary domain

and I did a pro subscription bundle [image]

this file netlify.toml

```
[[redirects]]
    from='/*'
    to='/index.html'
    status=200
    [[headers]]
  for = "/*"
  [headers.values]
    Strict-Transport-Security = '''
    max-age=63072000;
    includeSubDomains;
    preload'''
```

a Production domains in netlify

[image]